# Cut and paste a part of an MS Word document without renumbering

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some requirement specifications in MS Word format. These all use header numbering.

Sometimes I want to quote a paragraph of the document in another MS Word document. This is a bit time consuming because if I cut and paste then the header numbering is not preserved: it all gets renumbered in the new document.

Is there a way to paste MS word content while retaining the original numbering?

The closest I've seen to a solution is here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-HA010215708.aspx

This allows you to retain list numbering but doesn't seem to work with header numbering.

Comment: just a remark, I tend to not use automatic numbering, I do it manually, so am not at the mercy of ms word for that.

Answer (score 1):

You might beable to get away with directly referencing the text in the external document by using the IncludeText field. Hopefully it will include the list numbering as well. See this [page on IncludeText](http://daiya.mvps.org/includetext.htm) for details under "include only part of a source document:"